# Actions class doesn't work in selenium 3.5.2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written code for automating mouse hover actions:-

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement product=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Products']/em"));
WebElement catalogue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Master Catalog']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action mouseOverMenu = builder.moveToElement(product).build();
mouseOverMenu.perform();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
catalogue.click();
```

I want to firstly hover 'product' webelement and after hovering 'product' webelement 'catalogue' appears and want to click on 'catalogue' webelement.

but this code throws below exception, pls suggest:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0HLH9L7', ip: '192.168.168.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.Vz7r3MDL9N0a, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=54.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=528, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: cc3875ef-61fd-422c-86cb-3647fbf03d93
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:275)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
    at actionsClass.MoveTo.Moving(MoveTo.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Put Implicit wait or explicit wait.

Comment: @iamsankalp89:- already added implicit wait:- driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try changing browser and also try with latest selenium webdriver. Mostly confirm if behavior is same on all browsers or not

Answer (score 0):

try as following:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(product).moveToElement(catalogue).click().build().perform();
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
Actions act2 = act1.moveToElement(product).build();
act2.moveToElement(catalogue).click().build().perform();
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
Actions act2 = new Actions(driver);
act1.moveToElement(product).build();
Thread.sleep(4000);  //you can change this to explicit wait later
act2.moveToElement(catalogue).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: It's not working kushal, check this url.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911879/action-class-is-not-working-with-selenium-3-5-2

Comment: @JainishKapadia : Try EDITED part.

Comment: Kushal, I have tried your updated answer as well, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @JainishKapadia : try EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution by below code and its working fine in all the browser:

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(element).perform();

    WebElement subElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("iPads"));

    action.moveToElement(subElement);

    action.click();

    action.perform();
```

//Explanation: 
/*With some of the browser it happens that once mouse hover action is performed, the menu list disappear with in the fractions of seconds before Selenium identify the next submenu item and perform click action on it. In that case it is better to use ‘perform()’ action on the main menu to hold the menu list till the time Selenium identify the sub menu item and click on it.*/