# Action class is not working with selenium 3.5.3

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to drag and drop the element from one place to another place. So, I am using action class to achieve my functionality.

The problem is that my code is executed successfully, with out showing any error, but functionality goal is not achieve.

I have try the same code in firefox and chrome browser, but same issue is getting replicated in both the browsers.

Here is the site [url](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html).

My tried code:

```
driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[contains(text(), 'Draggable 1')]"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[contains(text(), 'Draggable 2')]"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[contains(text(), 'Draggable 3')]"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[contains(text(), 'Draggable 4')]"));

WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='w50 moveleft']//div[@id='mydropzone']"));
String[] array_drag = new String[] {"Draggable 1", "Draggable 2", "Draggable 3", "Draggable 4"};

for(int i=0; i<array_drag.length; i++)
{
    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='todrag']//span[contains(text(), '"+array_drag[i]+"')]"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    act.clickAndHold().moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2500);         
}
```

I have try this answer as well, but replicated the same issue.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(from).moveToElement(to).build().perform();
```

You can see the below attached image as well, code is executed successfully, without showing any error.

[image]

can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: is directly dragAndDrop in actions not working?

Comment: @murali selenium, yes it is also not working.

Comment: That website doesn't appear to be working as expected. I can't even drag/drop manually. Is the problem with the site, and not with your code?

Comment: Site is working properly, Through manually I can do easily drang and drop the webelement, in both the browsers. (firefox and chrome)

Answer (score 0):

we can try like this also

```
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(src)
        .moveToElement(trg)
        .release(trg)
        .build();  
        dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time @murali selenium, I have try your code, but replicate the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
                    builder.clickAndHold(weDragFrom).build().perform();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    builder.click(weDragTo).build().perform();
                    builder.release(weDragTo).build().perform();
```

`
Unfortunately, this works only on chrome for me but not in Firefox or IE11. Am still in search for a solution for to make this work . Tried everything as you say code run without any error nor does anything

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your code, But for me it is not working in any of these mentioned browsers. (Chrome, Firefox, IE11)