# Drag and Drop doesn't work inside iFrame with Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, webdriver, action

I am trying to perform drag and drop with Selenium and Java and it is not working.. What can be the cause.. It doesn't give me any error but it is just not happening..

Here is my code.

```
public class ActionDragDrop {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement f=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='iframeResult']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(f);

        WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='drag1']"));
        WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div1']"));

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Actions dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(drag);
        builder.moveToElement(drop);
        builder.release(drop);
        builder.build();
        dragAndDrop.perform();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: WHat is the error, u missing the setproperty

Comment: It is working fine with Chrome, the only thing is not happening is Drag and Drop. It doesn't give me any error.

Comment: So that is the logical issue

Comment: I clicked on elements individually and those are working fine. Only thing is not happening is drag and drop. I am not sure which kind of issue I am facing here.

Comment: ya i same facing issue , strange

Answer (score 0):

You will to switch to iframe first in order to perform drag and drop event:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);                      //Move inside to the frame. 
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//your xpath")); 
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();              //Move outside to the frame.

driver.switchTo().frame(1);                     //Move inside to another frame.
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("guide_RIGHT_SAFETY_rect"));
act.clickAndHold(to).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();                //Move outside to another frame.
```

Note : Kindly use your xpath, id, classname etc, I have just copied an example. More or less idea should be same.

Comment: I did the same using this code --- WebElement f=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='iframeResult']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(f);

Comment: Can you share POM of your page for which you are trying to achieve the same?

Comment: I am just running the simple java program using main method. Neither any frameworks nor Maven are attached to this.

Comment: @anshul Gupta, I guess `from` and `to` elements are in the same iframe, So no need to move from one iframe to another.

Comment: @JainishKapadia sure, I just gave him an example on how to do this iframe can be same.

Comment: Yes, both the elements are in the same iFrame, so once I switch to frame, I am all set to perform drag and drop within frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

As your `from` and `to` webelement is located inside the same `iframe`. First you need to switch inside the `iframe.`

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");   //Move inside to the frame. 
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='drag1']")); 
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div1']"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).perform();
Thread.sleep(4000);
act.clickAndHold().moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();    //Move outside to the frame.
```

Comment: Actually the problem is code execute successfully, Without showing any error. Please review my code at your end and see any errors are showing or not. I guess Action class is no more working latest selenium `3.5.3`

Comment: You can check my this question as well. refer this question for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911879/action-class-is-not-working-with-selenium-3-5-3

Comment: If you have another way to resolve this kind of issues, then please provide your suggestions. (Like Can we achieve this functionality without using action class?)

Comment: Yes, I will try. But this is strange

Comment: I also want to know why it is not working?? Is there anywhere documented whether this Action will not work with so and so version of selenium? I dont see it here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: Looks like there is something strange with this website, I tried another website and it is just working fine. http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as `Accepted`, as my code is working fine, without showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

I have done many experiments and finally found the solution as below code in Python.

The failure at DragAndDrop is not caused by iframe.

Just separate every step and perform it.

```
# drag leftbox and drop on rightbox

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click_and_hold(leftbox).perform()
sleep(4)
actions.move_to_element(rightbox).perform()
sleep(4)
actions.release(rightbox).perform()
```